# Close the Websocket connection using STOMP

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, stompjs

Currently, I have a project with Websocket and Stomp as the sub-protocol for messaging, I need to manage the disconnection event and reconnection event on the Websocket. **My ultimate goal is to close the WebSocket session with STOMP after 5 seconds if there is no message between server and client**. I am quite confused about heart-beat values when set in server and client. For example, I have these heart-beat values set in the client (using `Stomp.js`):

```js
stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 5000;
stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 1000;
```

And here is what I have for the heart-beat values on the server-side (Spring Boot):

```java
config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
                .setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler()).setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{5000, 5000});
```

So I set the value on the server-side it will send a PONG message every 5 seconds, but on the client-side, it expects to receive the message in 1s, but when it waits for more than one second, the connection is still there and the WebSocket is still working.

And if I change one of the values on one side and how it affects the other side? And how I can assert that the connection will be closed in the **specific time** with these heart-beat values? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) explains how heart-beating works. An agreement happens between the client and the broker when the connection is created where the *largest* heart-beat values will be used.

> The `heart-beat` header provides enough information so that each party can find out if heart-beats can be used, in which direction, and with which frequency.
>
> More formally, the initial frames look like:
>
> ```
> CONNECT
> heart-beat:<cx>,<cy>
>
> CONNECTED
> heart-beat:<sx>,<sy>
> ```
>
> For heart-beats from the client to the server:
>
> - if `<cx>` is 0 (the client cannot send heart-beats) or `<sy>` is 0 (the server does not want to receive heart-beats) then there will be none
> - otherwise, there will be heart-beats every `MAX(<cx>,<sy>)` milliseconds
>
> In the other direction, `<sx>` and `<cy>` are used the same way.

In your case the client specifies that it wants to receive heart-beats every 1 second, but the broker can only send pings every 5 seconds (based on the configuration you specified) so the client should only expect pings every *5* seconds (since 5 > 1).

Another example...If you had `cx, cy = 5000, 10000` and `sx, sy = 15000, 20000` the client would send heart-beats to the broker every 20 seconds (i.e. `MAX(<cx>,<sy>)`) and the broker would send heart-beats to the client every 15 seconds (i.e. `MAX(<sx>,<cy>)`).

Also, keep in mind that a heart-beat and a [`MESSAGE`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#MESSAGE) frame are two different things. If your client doesn't receive a `MESSAGE` frame the connection can still be valid and the client & broker can & will still exchange heart-beats during this time.

Comment: So for example so the server and client agree heart-beat values 5000, 5000. Then after 5 seconds one of them doesn't send the other the message then the connection will be closed?

Comment: And for example if I have `cx, cy = 5000, 10000` and `sx, sy = 15000, 20000`, then there will be the heart-beat send every 20 seconds in both directions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the message"? Are you talking about a heart-beat or a `MESSAGE` frame?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Here is my config for the heart-beat on the server side, I deliberately set up the time for at least 5 seconds to send and retrieve the message from the server, but when I look at the console I see the message from the server is sent to client faster than 5 seconds, perhaps 2.5 seconds for each message sent.

Comment: `registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic")
                .setTaskScheduler(getThreadPoolTaskScheduler())
                .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(5000)
                .setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(5000)
                .setTcpClient(createClient())
                .setClientLogin(brokerRelayUser)
                .setClientPasscode(brokerRelayPass)
`

Comment: `.setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved-user")
 .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/log-user-registry");
`

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by "message." Are you talking about an actual `MESSAGE` frame or a heart-beat? Keep in mind that the heart-beat configuration has *nothing* to do with how quickly clients will send or receive `MESSAGE` frames.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the heart-beats, they are sent more frequently than I expected, I configure for 5 seconds but 2.5s there is a heart-beat sent.

Comment: How are you determining the timing of the heart-beats? Is this making a meaningful difference in your application?

Comment: Yeah because I'm developing a calling project so timing is quite crucial. I try to set heart-beat for both client and server for 5 seconds, the client sends heart-beat every after 5 seconds but the server sends 2 heartbeats in 5 seconds interval.

Comment: How specifically does that impact your application? Heart-beats happen in the background. They really shouldn't impact an application aside from how long it takes to recognize a failed connection. Also, you never indicated how your determining the timing of the heart-beats.